# navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: colors, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How can I change the background color of the navbar of the Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.2? How can I change color of all the elements of the navbar to reflect the background color?

Comment: Solved.
Made changes in bootstrap.css

.navbar-inner {
  background-color: #2c2c2c;

changed background-color, commented everything else.

Thanks.

Comment: do not recommend you modify the bootstrap main css stylesheet simply because when you update the stylesheet all of your changes will be lost so just include whatever modification you need in your own stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks Andres, What are the other ways to change the behavior of the Bootstrap?
The navbar is a pain for most sites as they people are just not able to believe web is as good for aesthetics as it is for functionality.

Comment: You can actually overwrite most of the bootstrap rules inside your own stylesheet, you don't need to touch the bootstrap.css stylesheet at all. This way when the bootstrap is updated you can just update that right away and all of your changes will remain, and also in this manner you can overwrite the boostrap styles to fit your needs (be it fonts or colors) of your site.

Comment: Much simpler answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: httpTWBSColor - Generate your own Bootstrap navbar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18529465/876739

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can overwrite the bootstrap colors, including the `.navbar-inner` class, by targetting it in your own stylesheet as opposed to modifying the bootstrap.css stylesheet, like so:

```
.navbar-inner {
  background-color: #2c2c2c; /* fallback color, place your own */

  /* Gradients for modern browsers, replace as you see fit */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#333333), to(#222222));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #333333, #222222);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

  /* IE8-9 gradient filter */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#222222', GradientType=0);
}
```

You just have to modify all of those styles with your own and they will get picked up, like something like this for example, where i eliminate all gradient effects and just set a solid black background-color:

```
.navbar-inner {
  background-color: #000; /* background color will be black for all browsers */
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: none;
}
```

You can take advantage of such tools as the [Colorzilla Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and create your own gradient colors for all browsers and replace the original colors with your own.

And as i mentioned on the comments, i would not recommend you modifying the bootstrap.css stylesheet directly as all of your changes will be lost once the stylesheet gets updated (current version is <sup>v2.0.2</sup>) so it is preferred that you include all of your changes inside your own stylesheet, in tandem with the bootstrap.css stylesheet. But remember to overwrite all of the appropriate properties to have consistency across browsers.

Comment: `background-image: none;` six times?

Comment: @DamianNowak woh, just noticed that, thanks for the tip :D ultimate brain fart.

Comment: Thank you. It was making me crazy that I could not set background-color to whatever and get that to apply to the entire navbar.

Answer (score 30):

An excellent resource to see how to theme bootstrap is: [bootswatch.com](http://bootswatch.com/). It has nice examples and shows code as well. In short, they use lessc to recompile the bootstrap.css to your new color-theme.css. The nice thing of their approach is that is build on top of bootstrap, so when  bootstrap is updated, you just recompile.

Links about using lessc and bootstrap:

- [Using bootstrap with less](http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html)
- [Lessc.org](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: Wonderful resources Alexander. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you havent got time to learn "less" or do it properly, here's a dirty hack...

Add this above where you render the bootstrap nav bar HTML - update the colours as required..

```
<style type="text/css">   

.navbar-inner {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, green);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.067);
    min-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.btn-group.open .btn.dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: red;
}

.btn-group.open .btn.dropdown-toggle {
  background-color:lime;
}

.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar .nav li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle {
  color:white;
  background-color:Teal;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: white;
    float: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #ffffff;
}

.navbar .brand {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #ffffff;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-text {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-link {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-link:hover {
  color: white;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can download a custom version of bootstrap and set @navbarBackground to the color you want.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Bootstrap version 3.2.0 and it looks as though .navbar-inner doesn't exist any more.

The solutions here which suggest overriding .navbar-inner didn't work for me - the colour remained the same.

The colour only changed when I overrode .navbar as shown below:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #A4C8EC;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way currently to do the same would be to install LESS command line compiler using

```
$ npm install -g less jshint recess uglify-js
```

Once you have done this, then go to the less folder in the directory and then edit the file variables.less and you can change a lot of variables according to what you need including the color of the navigation bar

```
@navbarCollapseWidth:             979px;

@navbarHeight:                    40px;
@navbarBackgroundHighlight:       #ffffff;
@navbarBackground:                darken(@navbarBackgroundHighlight, 5%);
@navbarBorder:                    darken(@navbarBackground, 12%);

@navbarText:                      #777;
@navbarLinkColor:                 #777;
@navbarLinkColorHover:            @grayDark;
@navbarLinkColorActive:           @gray;
@navbarLinkBackgroundHover:       transparent;
@navbarLinkBackgroundActive:      darken(@navbarBackground, 5%);
```

Once you have done this, go to your bootstrap directory and run the command make.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using LESS, you can use Mixins for less code. Here I will add a gradient, border, and border-radius:

```
.navbar-inner {
  #gradient > .vertical(#ffffff, #ECECEC);
  border: #E2E2E2;
  .border-radius(6px);
}
```

*If you are using the rails gem, twitter-bootstrap-rails, I do this directly in the file bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less*

Answer (score 2):

that is what i do

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
  background-color: #E27403; /* it's flat*/
 background-image: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E27403, #E49037);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E27403, #E49037);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E27403, #E49037);
}
```

it works well for all navigator 
you can see demo here http://caverne.fr on the top

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap.css line 4784 we see:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
  background-color: #FFFFFFF;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#222222), to(#111111));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222, #111111);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #252525;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff222222', endColorstr='#ff111111', GradientType=0);
}
```

You need to remove all the 'background-image' property declarations to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't occam's razor say to just do this until you need something more complex?  It's a bit of a hack, but may suit the needs of someone that wants a quick fix.

```
.navbar-default .container-fluid{
    background-color:#62ADD7; // Change the color
    margin: -1px -1px 10px -1px; // Get rid of the border
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the LESS or SASS Version of the Bootstrap. The most efficient way is to change the variable name, in the LESS or SASS file.

```
$navbar-default-color:              #FFFFFF !default;
$navbar-default-bg:                 #36669d !default;
$navbar-default-border:             $navbar-default-bg !default;
```

This by far the most easiest and the most efficient way to change the Bootstraps Navbar. You need not write overrides, and the code remains clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your own version on the [Bootstrap official website](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

Answer (score 0):

I actually just overwrite anything I want to change in the site.css, you should load the site.css after bootstrap so it will overwrite the classes. What I have done now is just made my own classes with my own little bootstrap theme. Little things like this

```
.navbar-nav li a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover{

    background-color: #18678E;
    height: 61px;
}
```

I also changed the likes of the validations errors the same way.