# Trouble Overriding Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched the net for a way to override bootstraps CSS but have yet to have it work for me. I am trying to change the default `navbar` color without editing the `bootstrap.css` file.
I have tried putting the following in the head after loading `bootstrap.css`:

```css
.navbar-inner {
    background-color: #006633;
    background-image: -mox-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#006633), to(#006633));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006633, #006633);
    border-color: #006633;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff006633', endColorstr='#ff006633', GradientType=0);
}
```

This did not work so I tried putting it in its own CSS file and then loading that stylesheet like so:

**bootstrapOverload.css**

```css
.navbar-inner {
    background-color: #006633;
    background-image: -mox-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#006633), to(#006633));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006633, #006633);
    border-color: #006633;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff006633', endColorstr='#ff006633', GradientType=0);
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrapOverload.css">
```

When that didn't work I tried adding a custom class to element

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<div class="navbar-inner navbar-override"> <!-- added navbar-override -->
```

**bootstrapOverload.css**

```css
.navbar-override {
    background-color: #006633;
    background-image: -mox-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#006633), to(#006633));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006633, #006633);
    border-color: #006633;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff006633',     endColorstr='#ff006633', GradientType=0);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would really love to learn how to do this the right way if possible.

Comment: In addition to the answers below this link http://www.nzwhost.com/article/understanding-css-hierarchy may help

Comment: This is very similar to [change navbar color in twitter bootstrap 2 0 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196638/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-2-0-4) which has a very comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried adding the `!important` tag on each CSS line in order to tell the element to override bootstrap?

Something like this:

```
.navbar-override {
    background-color: #006633 !important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#006633), to(#006633)) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633) !important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006633, #006633) !important;
    border-color: #006633 !important;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff006633',     endColorstr='#ff006633', GradientType=0) !important;
}
```

Typically not the best way to do this, but I think it should work.

Comment: Perfect! This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

To overload css you need to either be later in the code, or more specific then the css you are trying to overload.

It may be possible to just add `body` in front of `.navbar-inner` so that it states `body .navbar-inner` just so that it is more specific, or maybe `div.navbar-inner`, the best would be to have an id there somewhere.

If you are selecting it as specific as is in the bootstrap.css, then I think you css is not loaded after the bootstrap as you think. Verify what is selected with a tool like Chromes development tool or Firefox's firebug.

Comment: In this case, there's no need to add unnecessary selectors

Comment: I just corrected some errors and tried adding body, div, and an id but it still doesn't work.  I also deleted my cache because I didn't know if that was preventing me from seeing the results for some reason.  When I inspect element with Chrome it is saying that it's still using bootstrap.css but when I uncheck all the values it displays the color from my style sheet.  I have my style sheet placed after bootstrap.css in my code.

Comment: What selector are `bootstrap.css` using for your element?

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your CSS:

```
background-image: -mox-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
```

I think it should be:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006633, #006633);
```

If you type a mistake in CSS, its stop interpreting the rest, so no override for you.

Comment: Awesome.  I didn't know it stopped rendering after one mistake.  To be sure I got it right this time I copied the css from bootstrap.css into my own style sheet and changed the color values.  Still no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Just spent most of the day trying to change the navbar color  : [

I think the problem is .navbar-inverse

Your separate .css file should include something like this then the color will change:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
background-color: #586214;
background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override the bootstrap defaults by changing the LESS variables.

[https://getbootstrap.com/2.0.1/less.html#variables](https://getbootstrap.com/2.0.1/less.html)

//Navbar

- @navbarBackground:               @Color1;
- @navbarBackgroundHighlight:          @Color1;
- @navbarBrandColor:               #FFFFFF;
- @navbarLinkColor:                #FFFFFF;
- @navbarLinkColorHover:               #FFFFFF;
- @navbarLinkColorActive:   #FFFFFF;
- @navbarInverseBackground:                    #FFFFFF;
- @navbarInverseBackgroundHighlight:           #FFFFFF;
- @navbarInverseBorder:                        #FFFFFF;
- @navbarInverseLinkColorHover:                @Color7;
- @navbarInverseLinkColorActive:           @Color11;
- @navbarInverseLinkColor:         @Color1;

Comment: we should also add that after changing the less files the css must be recompiled (or interpreted by lessjs)

Answer (score 0):

Solve your Problem by Copying the CSS-Class and rename it. Then use this class :)

I know its Boosted but look atleast it works

Example:

```
.drop-down {...}     /* is from bootstrap */
.drop-down-new {...} /* Your new Class that works*/
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to add bootstrap script in head section then add your own css file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).