# Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, bootstrap-5

How would I go about modifying the CSS to change the color of the navbar in Twitter Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1421, accepted):

> **tl;dr - [TWBSColor - Generate your own Bootstrap navbar](http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/e74c3cc0392becf0f1ffbbbc0)**
>
> **Version notes:**
>
> - Online tool: Bootstrap 3.3.2+ / 4.0.0+
> - This answer: Bootstrap 3.0.x
> - For Bootstrap 5.x, [please check documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/overview/)

### Available navbars

You've got two basic navbars:

```html
<!-- A light one -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>
<!-- A dark one -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation"></nav>
```

### Default color usage

Here are the main colors and their usage:

- `#F8F8F8`: navbar background
- `#E7E7E7`: navbar border
- `#777`: default color
- `#333`: hover color (`#5E5E5E` for `.nav-brand`)
- `#555`: active color
- `#D5D5D5`: active background

### Default style

If you want to put some custom style, here's the CSS you need to change:

```css
/* navbar */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
/* Title */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
/* Link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}
/* Caret */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #777;
    border-bottom-color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #333;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #555;
    border-bottom-color: #555;
}
/* Mobile version */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #777;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
          color: #333;
    }
}
```

### Custom colored navbar examples

Here are four examples of a custom colored navbar:

[image]

And the SCSS code:

```css
$bgDefault   : #e74c3c;
$bgHighlight : #c0392b;
$colDefault  : #ecf0f1;
$colHighlight: #ffbbbc;
.navbar-default {
  background-color: $bgDefault;
  border-color: $bgHighlight;
  .navbar-brand {
    color: $colDefault;
    &:hover, &:focus {
      color: $colHighlight; }}
  .navbar-text {
    color: $colDefault; }
  .navbar-nav {
    > li {
      > a {
        color: $colDefault;
        &:hover,  &:focus {
          color: $colHighlight; }}}
    > .active {
      > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgHighlight; }}
    > .open {
      > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgHighlight; }}}
  .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: $bgHighlight;
    &:hover, &:focus {
      background-color: $bgHighlight; }
    .icon-bar {
      background-color: $colDefault; }}
  .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-form {
    border-color: $colDefault; }
  .navbar-link {
    color: $colDefault;
    &:hover {
      color: $colHighlight; }}}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    > li > a {
      color: $colDefault;
      &:hover, &:focus {
        color: $colHighlight; }}
    > .active {
      > a, > a:hover, > a:focus, {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgHighlight; }}}
}
```

### And finally, a little gift

I've just made a script which will allow you to generate your theme:
**[TWBSColor - Generate your own Bootstrap navbar](http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/e74c3cc0392becf0f1ffbbbc0)**

*[Update]: TWBSColor now generates SCSS/SASS/Less/CSS code.* 
*[Update]: From now, you can use Less as the default language provided by TWBSColor* 
*[Update]: TWBSColor now supports drop down menus colorization*
*[Update]: TWBSColor now allows to choose your version (Bootstrap 4 support added)*

Comment: When I attempted to use the outputted color scheme, the colors did not show up. Adding `!important` to the end of each of the outputted CSS statements seems to have resolved the issue. Example:   `color: #ffffff;` becomes `color: #ffffff !important;`.

Comment: @Adrian : you should include the CSS file with these customizations after you include bootstrap's own css. Other reason can be for not working is if you use bootstrap-theme.css to give your site Boostrap 2.x like gradient look and feel

Comment: How to add the generated css from TWBSColor ? I am using bootstrap.min.css from netdna cdn in my python flask aaplication how to override default navbar with the one genertaed from TWBSColor?

Comment: just background instead of background-color works for me

Comment: After having generated and using the css using TWBSColor, I had to remove "bootstrap-theme.min.css" to get it working. I was not using bootstrap themes anyways...

Comment: @bchr02 are you sure you've include bootstrap before to write TWBSColor code?

Comment: @zessx I don't understand your question.

Comment: Why should it be so long code to override the color of single element??? and also: I managed to change it only by using !important and also: when pressing on other menu item the first menu item is still selected )-:

Comment: you can use bg-danger, bg-primary and more default colors to add color to your nav bar e.g . 

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default bg-danger">

Comment: @zessx What about if you have more than one navbar design in your application? I tried renaming the generated .navbar-default class but I didn't get the same result, it seems like the generated content doesn't declare everything navbar-default does (such as anchor hover background colours). Currently working round this by using both the navbar-default and navbar-custom class, it would be nice if the generated content permitted inputting a custom class name + was completely isolated like Jim's answer. Note, I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: Your TWBSColor tool is really a great time saver.  Any possibility of adding a height adjustment.  The default navbar is a bit too thick for my liking

Comment: Hi @Mike, glad you found TWBSColor useful! Unfortunately, this tool was focused on colors from the very beginning. It is quite old (gosh, 9 years…) and is already obsolete with the last [Bootstrap 5 Theming system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/overview/), I won't add new features to it. Thanks for your comprehension.

Answer (score 235):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

By default, the Navbar is transparent in Bootstrap 5. Not much has changed since Bootstrap 4 for changing the Navbar background color, text color, links, dropdown and hover styles..

```
/* change the background color */
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #4433cc;
}

/* change the brand and text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: #ffcc00;
}

/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffbb00;
}

/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:focus .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: pink;
}

/* for dropdowns only */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ddaa11;
}

/* dropdown item text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
}

/* dropdown item hover or focus */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Bootstrap 5 custom navbar color demo](https://codeply.com/p/fGj22m7OBN)

---

**Bootstrap 4.3 (update 2020)**

Changing the Navbar color is different (and a little easier) in **Bootstrap 4**. You can create a custom navbar class, and then reference it to change the navbar without impacting other Bootstrap navs..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">...</nav>
```

**Bootstrap 4.3+**

The CSS required to change the Navbar is much less in Bootstrap 4...

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
/* change the brand and text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 Custom Navbar Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/1ZFF5CEXM5/custom-navbar-color)[image]

Changing the active/hover link ***background* color** also works with the same CSS, but you must adjust the padding if you want the bg color to fill the full height of the link...

`py-0` to remove vertical padding from the entire navbar...

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-custom py-0">..</nav>`

```
/* change the link color and padding  */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    padding: .75rem 1rem;
}

/* change the color and background color of active links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 Change Link and Background Color Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/CzhP1QKxnW)

Also see: [How can I change the Bootstrap 4 navbar button icon color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586729/)

---

**Bootstrap 3**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">...
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
      </div>
       ...
    </nav>


    .navbar-custom {
        background-color:#229922;
        color:#ffffff;
        border-radius:0;
    }
      
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color:#fff;
    }
    
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color:transparent;
    }
          
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open >a {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #33aa33;
    }
         
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
        color:#eeeeee;
    }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
        background-color:#eeeeee;
    }
    .navbar-custom .icon-bar {
        background-color:#33aa33;
    }
```

[Custom Navbar Demo on Bootply](http://bootply.com/78010)

---

If the Navbar has dropdowns, add the following to change dropdown color(s):

```
/* for dropdowns only */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu  { 
  background-color: #33aa33;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a  { 
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus  { 
  color: #33aa33;
}
```

[Demo with Dropdown](http://www.bootply.com/Iq82PS84ZA)

---

If you want to **change the theme colors** all together (beyond the navbar), [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596794/customizing-bootstrap-css-template/50410667#50410667)

Comment: How can I change navbar li:hover background-color in your example?

Comment: The navbar button does not show up on small screens using this method.

Comment: this is the best solution as it avoid overwriting any css and worrying about using important!

Comment: I completely revamped my answer. It should provided *working solutions* for both for **3.x** and **Bootstrap 4**.

Comment: Yes, works as expected and all relevant code is in the answer @marcozen

Comment: I agree that the button does not show up on small screens, even in the codeply example.

Answer (score 51):

It took me a while, but I discovered that including the following was what made it possible to change the navbar color:

```
.navbar{ 
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this fixes the problem but thank you.

Comment: its because bootstrap adds this   /* background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #f8f8f8 100%); */ to add a gradient. Im not sure why they include this and the background-color though

Comment: @DanielKobe @Sumeet  I just checked Bootstrap code, and there's no `background-image` added, which would prevent TWBSColor to work. Could I know your Bootstrap's version, and your environment please? (additional theme, CSS libraries...)

Comment: @zessx it seems like it's themes causing this. I was using the simple theme for bootstrap 3.2.0 (CDN). Removing it solved the whole thing.

Comment: Setting background-image to 'none' seems to be the solution, at least for latest versions, where background-image has a specific gradient which retains the watery blue color, even when you custom specify a background-color. It's possible that the accepted answer for this question may have gone stale over time. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.

Comment: helped me to! i almost broke my brain and eyes trying to find out why background isn't changing

Answer (score 50):

## Using Less

You could also consider to compile your own version. Try http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ (which has a apart section for the Navbars settings (Default navbar and Inverted Navbar)) or download your own copy from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.

You will find the navbar settings in `variables.less`. `navbar.less` is used to compile the navbar (depends on `variables.less` and `mixins.less`).

Copy the 'navbar-default section' and fill in your own color settings. Changing the variables in `variables.less` will be the easiest way (changing the default or inverse navbar won't be a problem because you have one navbar per page only).

You won't change all settings in most cases:

```
// Navbar
// -------------------------

// Basics of a navbar
@navbar-height:                    50px;
@navbar-margin-bottom:             @line-height-computed;
@navbar-default-color:             #777;
@navbar-default-bg:                #f8f8f8;
@navbar-default-border:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);
@navbar-border-radius:             @border-radius-base;
@navbar-padding-horizontal:        floor(@grid-gutter-width / 2);
@navbar-padding-vertical:          ((@navbar-height - @line-height-computed) / 2);

// Navbar links
@navbar-default-link-color:                #777;
@navbar-default-link-hover-color:          #333;
@navbar-default-link-hover-bg:             transparent;
@navbar-default-link-active-color:         #555;
@navbar-default-link-active-bg:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);
@navbar-default-link-disabled-color:       #ccc;
@navbar-default-link-disabled-bg:          transparent;

// Navbar brand label
@navbar-default-brand-color:               @navbar-default-link-color;
@navbar-default-brand-hover-color:         darken(@navbar-default-link-color, 10%);
@navbar-default-brand-hover-bg:            transparent;

// Navbar toggle
@navbar-default-toggle-hover-bg:           #ddd;
@navbar-default-toggle-icon-bar-bg:        #ccc;
@navbar-default-toggle-border-color:       #ddd;
```

You could also try http://twitterbootstrap3navbars.w3masters.nl/. This tool generates CSS code for your custom navbar. Optionally, you could also add gradient colors and borders to the navbar.

Answer (score 11):

## Just add an id to the HTML navbar, such as:

```
<nav id="navbar-yellow" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

With this id you can style the navbar color, but also the links and dropdowns

## Examples applied to different types of navbars

[**Black**](http://www.bootply.com/pckUqtKEMD)

[**Yellow**](http://www.bootply.com/OkuzvC86sy)

[**Darkblue**](http://www.bootply.com/smQu15m8DP)

[**Red (Cherry)**](http://www.bootply.com/ODtOcZ2WOT)

[**Darkgreen**](http://www.bootply.com/r9Prza34wB)

## Here is the CSS

```
/*
 * Black navbar style
 */
#navbar-black.navbar-default { /* #3C3C3C - #222222 */
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(60, 60, 60, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(60, 60, 60, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:hover,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:focus,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
#sidebar-black, #column-black {
      background-color: #222222;
}
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #222222;
}
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #3C3C3C;
}
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #999999;
}
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#navbar-black.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*
 * Red navbar style
 */
#navbar-red.navbar-default { /* #990033 - #cc0033 */
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(153, 0, 51, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204, 0, 51, 1) 0%, rgba(153, 0, 51, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204, 0, 51, 1) 0%, rgba(153, 0, 51, 1) 100%);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:hover,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:focus,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
#sidebar-red, #column-red {
      background-color: #990033;
}
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #990033;
}
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #cc0033;
}
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #999999;
}
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#navbar-red.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*
 * Darkblue navbar style
 */
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default { /* #003399 - #0033cc */
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 153, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(51, 51, 153, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51, 51, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(51, 51, 153, 1) 100%);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:hover,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:focus,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
#sidebar-darkblue, #column-darkblue {
    background-color: #333399;
}
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #333399;
}
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #3333cc;
}
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #999999;
}
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#navbar-darkblue.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*
 * Darkgreen navbar style
 */
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default { /* #006633 - #009933 */
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 102, 51, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 153, 51, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 102, 51, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 153, 51, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 102, 51, 1) 100%);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:hover,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:focus,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
#sidebar-darkgreen, #column-darkgreen {
    background-color: #006633;
}
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #006633;
}
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #009933;
}
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #999999;
}
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#navbar-darkgreen.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*
 * Yellow navbar style
 */
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default { /* #99ff00 - #ccff00 */
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(153, 255, 0, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(153, 255, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(153, 255, 0, 1) 100%);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:hover,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a:focus,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
#sidebar-yellow, #column-yellow {
    background-color: #99ff00;
}
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #99ff00;
}
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ccff00;
}
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>ul>li>a,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #999999;
}
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#navbar-yellow.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Is the above for bootstrap 3 or 4 ?

Answer (score 7):

Do you have to change the CSS directly? What about...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #333399;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this too. This worked for me.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #00a950;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's only about changing the color of the Navbar my suggestion would be to use: [Bootstrap Magic](http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/app/#!/editor). You can change the values for different properties of the Navbar and see a preview.

Download the result as a custom CSS style sheet or as a Less variables file. You can change values with input fields and color pickers.

Answer (score 3):

In this navbar CSS, set to own color:

```css
/* Navbar */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
/* Title */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
/* Link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}
/* Caret */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #777;
    border-bottom-color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #333;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #555;
    border-bottom-color: #555;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set to own color"?

Answer (score 1):

#### Example

Just try it like this:

```
<!-- A light one -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>
<!-- A dark one -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation"></nav>
```

#### File `navabr.css`

```
/* Navbar */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
/* Title */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
/* Link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}
/* Caret */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #777;
    border-bottom-color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #333;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #555;
    border-bottom-color: #555;
}
/* Mobile version */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #777;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #333;
    }
}
```

**The default major color uses are as below:**

- Navbar Background: #F8F8F8
- Navbar Border: #E7E7E7
- Default Color: #777
- Nav-brand Hover Color: #5E5E5E
- Hover Color: #333
- Active Background: #D5D5D5
- Active Color: #555

You can learn more in *[To change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://fellowtuts.com/bootstrap/to-change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3/)*.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse and default class name mention in Twitter Bootstrap cause them to be black and white color.

Better, you should not override that and add a class near that and write you particular style for that:

```css
my_style{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation"></nav>

navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

[25+ Bootstrap Nav Menus Code](https://onaircode.com/best-responsive-bootstrap-navigation-menus/)