# Change twitter bootstrap 3.0 navbar class background color in less

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

in html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
```

in variable.less file:

```
@navbar-default-bg: #f8f8f8;
```

After change this hex colour to other colour(ie. blue), you will notice that only bottom edge colour change to blue. because the class navbar has background too, it block the @navbar-default-bg colour.

Sample:

1.in html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
```

in variable.less:

@navbar-default-bg: blue;

**Output**:[image]

2.in html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
```

in variable.less:

@navbar-default-bg: blue;

in custom.css:

.navbar{background: blue}

**Output**:[image]

I know that if I make a custom css file and put `.navbar{background: blue}` it will change the navbar color to what I want.

But I prefer to edit less file. is there any way to do that?
**Try on your end first before you think this is a duplicate question!**

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18553876/1596547

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Thanks Bass Jobsen.Before I post this question I already see the post. it missing navbar class in the less file. you can try on your end, you might have better understand my question.

Comment: Please see "in html" carefully. and before you think it is a duplicate question,try it on your end first please.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the default bootstrap-theme.css and bootstrap-theme.min.css files from your project as I think they over-ride some of the styles in the main bootstrap.css files.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is duplicate still. I think your conclusion above is not right.
When i set @navbar-default-bg: blue;(in variables.less) and rebuild the css (Bootstrap). `<div class="navbar navbar-default">` will give me a blue navbar like:

[image]

The `.navbar` class don't set a background color neither it does influence the background color of your navbar-default class.

At the moment you will always have to add a second class to the .navbar (like navbar-default, navbar-inverse or navbar-custom) class for styling the navbar. See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10332

After setting `@navbar-default-bg: blue;` and recompile bootstrap the css for .navbar-default will look like:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  border-color: #0000de;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #5e5e5e;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #777777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #777777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #0000de;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #dddddd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #0000de;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #333333;
  border-bottom-color: #333333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #0000de;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #555555;
  border-bottom-color: #555555;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #777777;
  border-bottom-color: #777777;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #0000de;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #777777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
```

Note `blue` will be set to `#0000FF;`

Comment: ok, if you say the .navbar does not set a background color. Could you try in html: <div class="navbar navbar-default"> and just change the @navbar-default-bg:blue see what happened?

Comment: yes i have done that, with the result shown in my answer. .navbar sets only: `.navbar {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.navbar {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}` and defines a `clearfix`

Comment: I've tried your answer, but the result is not the same. it returns only top and bottom margin colour changed to blue.

Comment: @Henry i don't know what happens in your case. To be sure i download the latest version.  I set `@navbar-default-bg: blue;` (in variables.less) and rebuild the css (Bootstrap). The result will be the same as shown in my answer and not like yours. I add the css for navbar-default after setting `@navbar-default-bg: blue;` to my answer.