# Style of Twitter's Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Howto change the styles of navbars in Twitter's Bootstrap 3 using Less or css? Using different styles as provide by the `navbar-default` and `navbar-inverse` classes.

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you asking a question? and why are you giving answers to your own questions ? i think Stack helps people to solve problems not to make them visit your own website or for Pub

Comment: @kougiland, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: I can't help but think this looks like a pointwhoring exercise. It's fine to answer your own question, but this question is far from constructive, and duplicates Bootstrap documentation

Comment: @Bojangles Bootstrap's docs don't tell you how to style a navbar, see: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar. Docs handle the structure of the navbar only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like buttons and panel a navbar will have two classes (see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10332). The first class (`.navbar`) will set the structure. The second class will set the styling. By default there will be two classes for styling: `.navbar-default` and `.navbar-inverse`. To change the style of your navbar you have to change the styles of these styling classes. The best way to do this is using Less and recompile Bootstrap.

### Using Less

The variables for `.navbar-default` and `.navbar-inverse` are set in variables.less and used by navbar.less. To define a custom navbar style you could modify the variable for `.navbar-default` or `.navbar-inverse` and reuse this classes. If you don't want to change the original code. Create an customnavbar.less file (don't forget ti import this in bootstrap.less) and copy the `.navbar-default` part from navbar.less to this file. Rename and set the variables. B.e. see here: [Change twitter bootstrap 3.0 navbar class background color in less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886309/change-twitter-bootstrap-3-0-navbar-class-background-color-in-less/18903743#18903743) to set the background to blue.

### Using CSS

Define your css just like `.navbar-default`. To change the style. B.e. for `<nav class"navbar navbar-custom">` and set background to blue;

`.navbar-custom { background-color: #0000FF;}`

For more styles and easy styling see: http://twitterbootstrap3navbars.w3masters.nl/