# Bootstrap Change Nav text color

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a rails application and now want to change the look of it. Currently I was able to make the background color of the navbar white (how I want it), but currently the text is a light gray and when it is hovered over it becomes white, which mean invisible. How do I fix this?

Here is the massive file with my styling custom.css

https://raw.github.com/MarcusHSmith/BattleOfTheBands/master/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

Any help would be appreciated.

I would like to change the text to default to black. thanks

Comment: So you have a similar question that relates to this post on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18529465/1217789. I think that @keithwyland is correct on drilling down through the nave bar child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom.css try:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #707070;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
}
```

(P.S. It's a bit hard to determine what exactly will work because you haven't provided the HTML that this CSS is applied to. I had to look at your github repo views erbs to determine that you are using `.navbar-inverse`. if you had a working page to link to or a jsfiddle, that would be even better.)