# Change the default header color in MVC5 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I've create MVC5 app ,in the view index the header color is black and I want to change it,where can I find it?

I try to search for #000000 but its in a lot places ...

Comment: yes but there is lot of places there...

Comment: The MVC5 template uses Bootstrap's navbar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: it will be in main.css

Comment: Try using Firebug (Firefox addon) and see where you have to change, also you can change it online to see the effect instantly

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In default MVC 5 web site, the background color of the header navigation bar is applied through `.navbar-inverse` css class available in `bootstrap.css` file under `\Content\bootstrap.css` folder of your project.

To change this style, you can override it in the Site.css file instead of changing the base bootstrap css file itself.

Simply adding the following to your Site.css file should change the background color of the navbar.:

```
.navbar-inverse { background-color: #ccc !important; }
```

Comment: That seemed to work in dev for me but not in production. This is what worked in production, go figure:         .navbar{ 
    background-image: none;
}

I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Just paste this in your site.css

```
/*green navbar*/ 
.navbar-inverse { background-color:#28a745 !important;  }
a.mynav {background-color:#28a745 !important;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a  
{color: #ffffff;} 
/* end of green navbar*/
```

in _Layout 
The Brand Name :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand active" })
```

For Any Navbar Item

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "mynav nav-item active" })</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make this change, go to: \Content\bootstrap.css

and find this code block:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border-color: #808080;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #39870C; // kind af green
}
```

in the `Site.css` file located in the `Content` folder to override the background-color.