# how to change the caret color of the active navigation

Tags: wordpress, css, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3, caret

I am using bootstrap 3. followed [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) in modifying the css. my problem is when the on active parent parent page, the caret is not the same color as the text. help please. thanks!

Comment: Do you have example code (essentially the HTML markup for your navigation *and* the CSS that you believe should be changing the color)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
.caret {
    color: red;
}
```

**Note:** For this to work, your CSS file should be referenced *after* Bootstrap's.