# How do I have different Nav Bar Colours?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, uinavigationbar

*Shortened the question, sorry for the confusion, and broadness*.
Okay, so I would like the navigation bar to be transparent when I'm on a certain `section`, and a uniform colour for every other section on the page.

So to summarise, one colour for the Nav Bar on a particular `section` or `div`.

I know I could probably use `rgba`, but I'm not sure how I could achieve assigning a new colour once the next section comes into view.

I'm new to Bootstrap, so please, keep it simple.

Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad and will probably be put on hold, but you should look into Bootstrap's Scrollspy and similar utilities. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that link out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the main colors and their usage :

```
#F8F8F8 : navbar background
#E7E7E7 : navbar border
#777 : default color
#333 : hover color (#5E5E5E for .nav-brand)
#555 : active color
#D5D5D5 : active background
```

Also, here is a link to the page i found it: [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)