# Bootstrap - Change Color of navbar-fixed-top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
...
</nav>
```

And I want to change the color of the navbar class above. I have tried using this code unsuccessfully to brute force changing the color:

```
.navbar {
  .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    background-image: none;
  }
}

/* navbar */
.navbar-fixed-top {
    background-color: #990099;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

NOTE: I tried the solution of a related question using [TWBSColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3/18553876#18553876) but it didn't work unless I changed navbar-fixed-top to navbar which I don't want to do.

Comment: this seems to work fine. Can you clarify what color you want your `<nav>` to be? What order are you loading your css?

Comment: There is CSS to override. See this example: http://bootply.com/qTu1FldGZl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the Bootstrap css you have to place your custom CSS BELOW the link to bootstrap.

It is the class Navbar-inverse that you need to change or replace with your own custom CSS.

Just changing the navbar-inverse will do it.

Answer (score 1):

As AngularJR said, you either have to add your css after the bootstrap css include or add !important to the css rule you want changed