# Bootstrap CSS text color not changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text-coloring

I'm making a website with Bootstrap, and I want to change the text color of my navbar. I was having difficulties even targeting the navbar, but that's besides the point. Basically, I just want to change the text color. It lets me change anything I want *other* than the text color, such as the background color, the font, the borders, etc, other than the text color. Here's a link to the [GitHub](https://github.com/LordMastodon/Kraken-Web-Page) of the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated (my css is in css/style.css, and the color tag is in the .nav, .navbar, .dropdown-menu class).

**EDIT 1** I've updated my GitHub code but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: When you are dealing with existing styles, you can use developer tools `F12` in Chrome to find out what css rules are applying to an element.  Then you can find out just how specific you need to be with your selectors to override.

Comment: I've updated my GitHub, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line controlling font-color on nav bar currently is in **bootstrap.css** and reads as follows:

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {  color: #777;}`

Inside **style.css** - you have tried to change the color in a few places, mainly here:

`.navbar-default, .navbar-nav > li > a, .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #c8f57a;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #2d4207;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans",sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}`

You may set precedent for your style.css rule to take priority by adding `!important` after the `color:2d4207;`. so, the new CSS in **style.css** would read as follows:

`.navbar-default, .navbar-nav > li > a, .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #c8f57a;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #2d4207 !important;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans",sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}`

You may read up on CSS Specificity here: [developer Mozilla - Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)