# Bootstrap Navbar 2 Background Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you help me to make this possible, newbie, i want 2 background color in one navbar. different background color for the logo and also for the menu please check my screenshot below, and i will copy and paste my bootstrap html here thank you

[NavBar ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Qfd.png)

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">News & Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Career</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: do you want http://jsfiddle.net/n2jy53v4/1/ this type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following CSS.

```
.container div.navbar-header
{
        background-color: white;
}

.container div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1
{
        background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container div.navbar-header{background-color: #eeeeee;}

.container div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{background-color: #f82225;}
```

Comment: Consider adding explaination to this answer. Code only Answers are often unhelpful and do not provide sufficient explaination to the OP.