# Why is my bootstrap navbar css not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to use this [bootstrap generator](http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/e74c3cc0392becf0f1ffbbbc0) which was recommended in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)
The generated code doesn't change anything, and my guess is I messed up on my labeling somewhere.

```
<div style="background-color: #18305c">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Home
        </button>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Browse <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Latest Offers</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Newest Listings</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Clearance</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Search</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Blog</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

The css looks like

```
 .navbar-default {
 background-color: #18305c;
 border-color: #d49418;
 }
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
color: #ffffff;
 }
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
color: #ffffff;
}
 .navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Why is it not changing?

Edit: Wanted to add this is only the top of the nav bar. There are a few more buttons with similar dropdown.

Comment: please create one plnkr

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: write your code in https://plnkr.co/ , here we can run the code, and that might help anyone to figure out the issue easily

Comment: Here is the codepen-http://codepen.io/niners52/pen/eZWajm

Comment: did you add the links and/or script tags for the bootstrap cdns?

Comment: What do you need help changing? There is no .navbar-brand and no .navbar-text anywhere in the html that you posted.  Only the navbar default class and that background is changing just fine https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/ghde2101/  So I am confused as to what you are having issues with

Comment: I did add the script tags for the cdns.

Comment: The buttons are supposed to be blue and the text is supposed to be white.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So by reading the above comments, you want to change the button color.

You have used the class `btn-default`, If you want the button color to be of blue change its class to `btn-primary`.

Checkout this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split) for various button colors.

Comment: I don't want to use the standard colors. I am trying to use this- http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/

Comment: Okay. Then you can customize the bootstrap css. Give a specific ID to the element . For example button and change the background color.

 <button type="button" id="home" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home</button>

//CSS
#home{background-color:violet}