# Navigation bar position 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Logo and li are closer to centre even though I have specified navbar-right. On my mac 13' looks good but on my PC in office looks different. Also picture is not really responsive and `.img-responsive` doesn't do anything.

```css
.navbar {
   min-height: 80px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
#btnnavbar {
   margin-top: 20px;
}

#btnhome {
   margin-top: 16px;
}

#imgbrand {
   margin-top: -70px;
   margin-left: px;
   height: 220px;
   width: 280px;
}

#firstpage {
   margin-top: 90px;
}

.button {
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
         <head>
         </head>
          <body>
            <!-- Navbar style available in Bootstrap framework-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
              <!-- /end-->
              <!-- Anything that has to be responsive we are going to keep inside the Bootstrap grid -->
              <div class="container">
                <!-- /end -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="btnnavbar">
              <!-- For screen readers only -->
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <!-- /end -->
               <!-- Hamburger menu button appears when browser window has been shrinked -->
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <!-- /end -->
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <a class="navbar-brand " href="http://codepen.io/ekilja01"><img class="img-responsive" id="imgbrand" src="http://www.kiljakandweb.com/favicon.png" alt="brand logo"></a>
                  
                </div>
                
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
         
            </div>
        </nav>
             
          
          <div class="container" id="firstpage">
          
                <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">1.4.1.3</h1>
          </div>
          </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I think that replace `<div class="container">` with `<div class="container-fluid">` has to solve the issue.  And you didn't specify the value of `margin-left` at `#imgbrand`

Comment: @Banzay Thank you! Fixed!

Comment: I placed a comment as an answer. Vote it, pls

Comment: Also can you please tell me how to change buttons color and hover background color in navbar. I've tried everything all classes and id selectors but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that replace `<div class="container">` with `<div class="container-fluid">` has to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change class "container" to container-fluid inside the navbar as Banzay said.

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#btnnavbar {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#btnhome {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
#imgbrand {
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: px;
  height: 220px;
  width: 280px;
}
#firstpage {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
.button {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar style available in Bootstrap framework-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- /end-->
    <!-- Anything that has to be responsive we are going to keep inside the Bootstrap grid -->
      <!-- /end -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="btnnavbar">
          <!-- For screen readers only -->
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <!-- /end -->
          <!-- Hamburger menu button appears when browser window has been shrinked -->
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- /end -->
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <a class="navbar-brand " href="http://codepen.io/ekilja01">
          <img class="img-responsive" id="imgbrand" src="http://www.kiljakandweb.com/favicon.png" alt="brand logo">
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container" id="firstpage">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">1.4.1.3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```