# How do I make this navbar transparent?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've been fiddling with the css for a long time now, nothing's working.

I succeeded in changing the text colors, but the background color remains stubborn

source: blackdeath1098.github.io

Comment: please add you code

Comment: Where you tried background-color just try background for your nav it will work.

Comment: Also try to set ```background-image: none;``` for ```navbar-default```.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 2):

You have used...

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

What you should be using instead...

```
.navbar-default {
    background: transparent;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/XNvNjv)**

Comment: I'm running prepros, and it doesn't show the change, still the same solid background.

Comment: Did you try setting the value, or did you try overriding the rule if thats the case then you can try by using `background: transparent!important;` just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have used...

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

What you need to be use instead...

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #ccffff;">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```