# Change css for li with class active Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap on my page:

```
<?php echo '<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active" id="one"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>';?   >
 <?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE['id']) and isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) {
 echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
 }
 ?>
 <?php echo '</ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>';
```

I want to change background for li with class active:

```
 li .active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

But my code doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active{
  color: #000; background: red;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #000;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

remove space between `li . active` changed `li.active` elements

**css**

```
 li.active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/odw3tyyL/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```css
li.active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try it :

```
li.active{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```