# How to change the navbar color in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried several methods to change the color of my navigation menu links but no result found!

For example I did this:

```
.navbar {
min-height:32px !important;
background-color:#0061ab !important;
color:#fff !important;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

And the result is this:

[image: print screen]

So how to fix that ?

Comment: Can you post your HTML snippet of your navbar?

Comment: Does your navbar markup has the `.navbar-custom` class on it?

Comment: try: .navbar a{color: #fff !important;}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new custom css file and linking that after bootstrap.css might help overriding the bootstrap ui classes.

There is also separate thread about twitter bootstrap.
[Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)