# How to change the default-navbar background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used a template from bootstrap for my navbar. I am using the default-navbar class. I was wondering how I can change the `background-color` and other properties of this `class` in the css. Right now when I create a style with the class `.navbar-default` and try to change the background color, it doesn't work. I think I have to create a custom style sheet to overide this? If so, how do I do this, and where would I place the text for the custom style sheet, if that's what I have to do? Here's my code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either add a new class like `navbar-custom` and add the class in a custom.css and in custom.css

```
.navbar-custom { background-color: red !important; }
```

and in your markup write

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
```

or you can do

```
<nav class="navbar-default" style="background-color: red">
```

for example and replace red with whatever color you like

Comment: I tried making a custom navbar but I ran into a couple problems with the dropdown toggle not showing up. I stuck the default and just put !important; after my background color and that solved the problem. Or I could have edited in the HTML like you did but I am planning on adding more styles to the navbar-default.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `!important` to the `background-color`.

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access and the editing-authorization to the style sheet (defined as the web address in the CSS code i.e. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) then only you will be able to change the desired parameters using background-image or background-color...otherwise that might not be possible!

Further you may also try opening that url address (where your CSS stylesheet has been saved i.e. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.csson a browser, copying the CSS code to an IDE, editing the desired parameters and linking the css of your website to the newly created (edited) style sheet! This might work.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the *navbar-header* class into the following code and put the important in the code

```
.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container>.navbar-header {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    background-color: blanchedalmond !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #c11111 !important;
}
```