# can't view toggle button in navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wrote a code of a toggle button to be seen when the screen size of the 
    browser is reduced on the navbar using bootstrap4 but the button is not 
    showing please what is wrong with my code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
   <button class="navbar-toggler " data-toggle="collapse" data- 
      target="#navbarcollapse">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapse">
      <ul class ="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item  active"><a href="#"class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">Downloads</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you share your code so we can see whats the problem?

Comment: its been adjusted please check again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added `bg-light navbar-light` and the button was visible.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light">
   <button class="navbar-toggler"  type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcollapse">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapse">
      <ul class ="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"class="nav-link">Downloads</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it works but i added a css to the navbar to change its color, how can i choose any preferable color to add to the navbar instead of white and black.

Comment: you can do it refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap