# Change background color in navbar fixed menu bar Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to change the color of my navbar fixed menu bar in Bootstrap.
In application.css.scss I have this:

```
.navbar
  .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
  }
}
```

In application.html.erb I have this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar-inner">
```

Could someone explain why I'm still seeing black as the menu bar background (I suspect I am not matching the classes quite right).

Comment: possible duplicate of [navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869610/navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the nav bar uses a css gradient. This uses the `background-image` property. You will need to reset this value as well:

```
.navbar {
  .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

Update: Added missing brace.

Comment: Ben, thanks very much! One question, is it correct to say that the "classes" are really "navbar" and "navbar-inner"? In other words, the "navbar-inverse" and "navbar-fixed-top" are not the classes, but are qualifications added on to the classes?

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .navbar {
        background-color:#00FFCC;
        background-image: none;
    }
</style>
```

just use this code you have some logical errors in your css