# Rails/Bootstrap: How do I change the black bar at the top?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, customization

Chapter 5 of railstutorial.org (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top) talks about how to create a basic layout for a web site.  I use it as a resource for putting a Rails web site together.

I'm having difficulty customizing the navbar/header.  While changing the font color of the "sample app" logo is straightforward enough (just change the RGB setting of the color parameter under #logo), how do I change parameters in the rest of the header?  How do I change that black bar to be some other color, such as dark blue/green/red/purple/brown/etc.?  How do I change the color of the menu links (Home/Help/Sign Up) from the default gray to yellow?  Or orange?  Or some other color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change color or customize style of twitter bootstrap (e.g header, link etc), you can use generator for twitter bootstrap..

### Generator

- [twitter bootstrap generator](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html)
- [StyleBootstrap](http://stylebootstrap.info/)
- [bootstrapthemeroller](http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/twitter-bootstrap-themeroller.html)
- [decioferreira](http://decioferreira.github.io/bootstrap-generators/)

Or if you don't know class/id potition of style, you can use inspect element on your browser and see element using class/id of style

### Example

Header using blue color

```
.navbar-inner {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #45aeea;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#54b4eb,#2fa4e7);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#54b4eb),to(#2fa4e7));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#54b4eb,#2fa4e7);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#54b4eb,#2fa4e7);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#54b4eb,#2fa4e7);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #1990d5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff54b4eb',endColorstr='#ff2fa4e7',GradientType=0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.065);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.065);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.065);
   }
```

Link header using white color

```
.navbar .nav>li>a {
   float: none;
   padding: 10px 15px 10px;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ce4213;
}
```

### Bootstrap themes

You can see some amazing bootstrap themes [here](http://bootswatch.com/)

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me.

Note to lurkers: When changing the background color from black to something else for the first time, choose a bright color.  If the color you choose is too dark to be easily distinguishable from black, you'll think what you did isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar {
    .navbar-inner {
        background-color: #2c2c2c;
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Source [Change background color in navbar fixed menu bar Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486488/change-background-color-in-navbar-fixed-menu-bar-bootstrap)

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869610/navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap) too.