# Change navbar text color Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors

I currently have this piece of html which represents the relevant part of my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> R&eacute;sum&eacute;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And I have this piece of css which I was hoping to use to change the text color of the navbar:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
    color: blue;
}
```

The only problem is that the text color remains unchanged.
I also saw that a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974873/unable-to-change-color-of-navbar-in-bootstrap-3) went unsolved. I bet whoever can solve this one can solve the other too.

Comment: You will probably have to target the li as well. Have you tried `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a` ? Or you could style each individual a tag with the font-color by giving it a class.

Comment: Doing the " a" worked. If you post this as an answer, I will award you the question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Make it the following:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: blue;
}
```

The above will target the specific links, which is what you want, versus styling the entire list blue, which is what you were initially doing. Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3usW/).

The other way would be creating another class and implementing it like so:

HTML

```
<li><a href="#" class="color-me"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> R&eacute;sum&eacute;</a></li>
```

CSS

```
.color-me{
    color:blue;
}
```

Also demonstrated in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3usW/2/)

Comment: Is there any way to make the toggle button blue too?

Comment: This no longer works in bootstrap 5.x

Answer (score 22):

As of bootstrap 4, the answer is to simply set navbar-dark in the nav element, which will set the text and links to a light theme .

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
```

Comment: I don't know why this is not rated higher.

Answer (score 16):

```css
    .nav-link {
       color: blue !important;
    }

 /* Worked for me. Bootstrap v4.3.1 */
```

Answer (score 9):

For changing the text color in navbar you can use inline css as;

```
<a style="color: #3c6afc" href="#">
```

Comment: For some reason none of the other solutions worked for me. Only this one did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The thread you linked to does answer the question for you. You need to target the `a` elements themselves. E.g.

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a {
    color: blue;
}
```

If that doesn't work, it just needs to be more specific. E.g.

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, we can simply use the **standard bootstrap text colors**, instead of *hacking the CSS formats*.

Standard Color examples: `text-primary`, `text-secondary`, `text-success`, `text-danger`, `text-warning`, `text-info`

In the Navbar code sample bellow, the text `Homepage` would be in the orange color (`text-warning`).

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-warning" href="/" > Homepage </a>
```

In the Navbar menu item sample bellow, the text `Menu Item` would be in the blue color (`text-primary`).

```
<a class="dropdown-item text-primary" href="/my-link">Menu Item</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Add `navbar-dark` class in the `<nav>` tag like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a span{
    color: blue;
}
```

If it doesn't work try this

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will work ,

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li .navbar-item ,
.navbar .navbar-brand{
                       color: red;
                      }
```

paste in your css and run
if you have a element below

define it as .navbar-item class

eg .

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home", new { area = "" },
 new { @class = "navbar-item" })</li>
```

OR

```
<li> <button class="navbar-item">hi</button></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css:

```
#ntext{
 color: #000000;
  }
```

Then the following in all your navigation bar list codes:

```
<li><a href="#" id="ntext"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the background colour of the navbar, you can do the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color=#e3f2fd">
```

And to change the text:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#ccc">
```

Comment: OP has asked for the text color of the link, not the background color

Answer (score 0):

Thanks WChoward for your answer.
I expanded:

```
.nav-link, .dropdown-item {
    color: blue !important;
}
.nav-link:hover, .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: darkgreen !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some inline css to the anchor tag

```
<li><a style = "color:blue" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> About</a></li>
```

This should add the color blue to the anchor tag text.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just do

```css
li a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Furthermore please explain why your answer is preferable to the others.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5.2.3 the following works:

```css
a.nav-link{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

The syntax is :

```
.nav navbar-nav .navbar-right > li > a {
   color: blue;
}
```