# Change color of bootstrap nav text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the text color inside my bootstrap links. I am trying to use the same method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420080/change-navbar-text-color-bootstrap) post but that solution is not working. How do I change the color of the text? Thank you. [This](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ab03100c2e152c19a899f90e38e7a6aa?editors=1100) is the codepen of the entire code.

Markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <img src="images/DISA.png" height="40">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">EU34</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Support Tracker</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Rolling Log</a></li>                
    </ul>
    <img src="images/DISALogoEUROPE.png" style="margin-left: auto; padding-right: 20px;" height="50">
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar.navbar-nav.nav-item li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: use `!important` .. like this .. maybe it will work.. `color: red !important;`

Comment: you should never use `!important` as there is no need to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the color override the bootstrap classes.

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: gold;
}
```

and to change color on hover or focus.

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class in bootstrap, like this :

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-primary">EU34</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, using class to override bootstrap class.

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{
  color:#00cc00
}
```

**[`Codepen demo`](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/XWdoPBz)**